# Python toolbox for OpenStreetMap data

Tags: python, plugin, geospatial, arcpy

**Background**

My project is a [Python toolbox](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/analyze/creating-tools/a-quick-tour-of-python-toolboxes.htm). This is my first bigger coding project and it took me quite some time to code this toolbox. I learned a lot from the start point to this day. I changed this code hundreds of times, whenever I learned about new trick or method. **This code works**. I tested it with various datasets, fixed bugs or any syntax errors.

**Cons:**

- The code ha some Polish names for: variable, functions etc.
- GUI is all Polish
- I started using Python about 3 months ago

**What my code does:**

Main purpose of this toolbox was to automate [OpenStreetMap (OSM)](https://www.openstreetmap.org/about) data transformation from voivodeship shapefiles into country sized one, from which values were selected  by their attributes to visualize features (for example, roads were selected and symbolized).

The code consists of three classes which are  three scripts inside of my toolbox.

It is used in [ArcGIS Pro](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/get-started/overview-of-arcgis-pro.htm) to help non-programmer user to replicate my work.

**My goal**

Can someone who is more experienced than me in Python give me some useful advice?

**Terms used in this code**

- shp - [shapefile](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shapefile)
- osm - OpenStreetMap
- fc - feature class
- gdb - geodatabase

I added comments to my code to help understand what is happening.

**My code**

```
# -*- coding: CP1250 -*-
import arcpy
import os
import pandas as pd
import shutil
import xlrd
from xml.etree import ElementTree as ET
import glob
from itertools import starmap
import re


class Toolbox(object):
    def __init__(self):
        """Define the toolbox (the name of the toolbox is the name of the
        .pyt file)."""
        self.label = "NardzedziaDoEskportu"
        self.alias = ""

        # List of tool classes associated with this toolbox
        self.tools = [Przygotowanie_do_eksportu, SkryptDoEksportu, XML_export]


class SkryptDoEksportu(object):
    def __init__(self):
        """Define the tool (tool name is the name of the class)."""
        self.label = "OSM Polska"
        self.description = "Skrypt eksportuje wybrane kolumny zawarte w tabeli atrybutow klas obiektow z geobazy."
        self.canRunInBackground = False

    def getParameterInfo(self):
        """Define parameter definitions"""
        # Pierwszy parametr
        inside = arcpy.Parameter(
            displayName="Wejsciowa geobaza",
            name="in_gdb",
            datatype="DEWorkspace",
            parameterType="Required",
            direction="Input")

        # drugi  parametr
        klasy = arcpy.Parameter(
            displayName="Warstwy w geobazie (mozliwy tylko podglad)",
            name="fcs_of_gdb",
            datatype="DEFeatureClass",
            parameterType="Required",
            direction="Input",
            multiValue=True)

        # trzeci parametr
        kolumny = arcpy.Parameter(
            displayName="Wybierz kolumny do selekcji",
            name="colli",
            datatype="GPString",
            parameterType="Required",
            direction="Input",
            multiValue=True)
        kolumny.filter.type = "ValueList"

        # Czwarty parametr
        plikExcel = arcpy.Parameter(
            displayName="Plik *.XLS z domenami",
            name="excelik",
            datatype="DEType",
            parameterType="Required",
            direction="Input")

        # Piaty parametr
        plikShpWoj = arcpy.Parameter(
            displayName="Plik *.Shp okreslajacy granice wojewodztw",
            name="ShpWoj",
            datatype="DEShapefile",
            parameterType="Required",
            direction="Input")

        # Szosty parametr
        plikBoundary = arcpy.Parameter(
            displayName="Plik *.Shp bedacy poprawiona wersja Polska_boundary_ply",
            name="shpBoundary",
            datatype="DEShapefile",
            parameterType="Required",
            direction="Input")

        p = [inside, klasy, kolumny, plikExcel, plikShpWoj, plikBoundary]
        return p

    def isLicensed(self):
        """Set whether tool is licensed to execute."""
        return True

    def updateParameters(self, parameters):
        """Modify the values and properties of parameters before internal
        validation is performed.  This method is called whenever a parameter
        has been changed."""
        parameters[1].enabled = 0

        if parameters[0].value:
            arcpy.env.workspace = parameters[0].value
            fclist = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses()
            parameters[1].value = fclist

            if parameters[1].value:
                fcs = parameters[1].value.exportToString()
                single = fcs.split(";")
                fields = arcpy.ListFields(single[0])
                l1 = [f.name for f in fields]
                l2 = ["OBJECTID", "Shape", "OSMID", "osmTags", "osmuser", "osmuid", "osmvisible",
                      "osmversion", "osmchangeset", "osmtimestamp", "osmMemberOf", "osmSupportingElement",
                      "osmMembers", " Shape_Length", "Shape_Area", "wayRefCount"]
                l3 = [czynnik for czynnik in l1 if czynnik not in l2]
                parameters[2].filter.list = l3
        return

    def updateMessages(self, parameters):
        """Modify the messages created by internal validation for each tool
        parameter.  This method is called after internal validation."""

    def execute(self, parameters, messages):

        # Variables
        arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True
        gdb = parameters[0].valueAsText
        wybor_uzytkownika = parameters[2].valueAsText
        excel = parameters[3].valueAsText
        granice_woj_shp = parameters[4].valueAsText
        boundary_ply_shp = parameters[5].valueAsText

        arcpy.env.workspace = gdb
        warunek = " <> ''"
        tymczasowa_nazwa = "tymczasowaNazwaDlaFC"
        lista_ln = []
        lista_ply = []
        lista_pt = []

        # Appends feature classes to lists and then merges them to single fc based on geometry 
        fc_lista = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses()

        listy_append(
            fc_lista, lista_ln, lista_ply, lista_pt)

        tupel_merge = (
            [lista_ln, "Polska_ln"],
            [lista_ply, "Polska_ply"],
            [lista_pt, "Polska_pt"])

        list(starmap(
            arcpy.Merge_management,tupel_merge))

        fc_lista = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses()

        # Deleting useless feature classes
        for fc in fc_lista:
            czlon_nazwy = fc.split("_")
            if czlon_nazwy[0] != "Polska":
                arcpy.Delete_management(fc)

        # Column split
        kolumny_split(
            wybor_uzytkownika, tymczasowa_nazwa, warunek, 
            gdb, granice_woj_shp, boundary_ply_shp)

        # File import from excel to create domain lists
        import_excel(
            excel, gdb)

        # Adding domains
        nadaj_domene(
            gdb, wybor_uzytkownika)

        return

class XML_export(object):
    def __init__(self):
        """Define the tool (tool name is the name of the class)."""
        self.label = "Eksport danych z XML"
        self.description = "Skrypt przygotowuje dane i eksportuje wybrane aspkety z XML"
        self.canRunInBackground = False

    def getParameterInfo(self):
        """Define parameter definitions"""
        # Pierwszy parametr

        inside = arcpy.Parameter(
            displayName = "Wejsciowa geobaza",
            name = "in_gdb",
            datatype = "DEWorkspace",
            parameterType = "Required",
            direction = "Input",
            multiValue = False)

        # drugi parametr

        rodzaj = arcpy.Parameter(
            displayName = "Wybierz typ geometrii",
            name = "geom",
            datatype = "GPString",
            parameterType = "Required",
            direction = "Input",
            multiValue = False)

        rodzaj.filter.type = "ValueList"    
        rodzaj.filter.list = ['pt','ln','ply']

        # trzeci parametr
        klasy = arcpy.Parameter(
            displayName = "Wybrane klasy",
            name = "fcs_of_gdb",
            datatype = "DEFeatureClass",
            parameterType = "Required",
            direction = "Input",
            multiValue = True)

        # czwarty
        wojewodztwa_string = arcpy.Parameter(
            displayName = "Wybierz wojewodztwa",
            name = "colli",
            datatype = "GPString",
            parameterType = "Required",
            direction = "Input",
            multiValue = True)

        wojewodztwa_string.filter.type = "ValueList"


        #piaty
        warstwa = arcpy.Parameter(
            displayName = "Wybierz warstwe",
            name = "fl_gdb",
            datatype = "GPFeatureLayer",
            parameterType = "Required",
            direction = "Input")

        # szosty
        wyrazenie = arcpy.Parameter(
            displayName = "Wpisz wyrazenie do selekcji",
            name = "expres",
            datatype = "GPSQLExpression",
            parameterType = "Required",
            direction = "Input")

        wyrazenie.parameterDependencies = [warstwa.name]

        # siodmy
        folder_xml = arcpy.Parameter(
            displayName = "Wskaz folder gdzie znajduja sie pliki w formacie XML",
            name = "XMLdir",
            datatype = "DEFolder",
            parameterType = "Required",
            direction = "Input")

        # osmy

        folder_csv = arcpy.Parameter(
            displayName = "Wskaz folder gdzie maja zostac zapisane pliki CSV",
            name = "CSVdir",
            datatype = "DEFolder",
            parameterType = "Required",
            direction = "Input")

        #dziewiaty
        kolumny = arcpy.Parameter(
            displayName = "Wybierz kolumne",
            name = "colli2",
            datatype = "GPString",
            parameterType = "Required",
            direction = "Input",
            multiValue = False)
        kolumny.filter.type = "ValueList"

        #dziesiaty
        check_1 = arcpy.Parameter(
            displayName = "Zaznacz aby dokonac zapisu do CSV (niezalecane odznaczanie)",
            name = "check1",
            datatype = "GPBoolean",
            parameterType = "Optional",
            direction = "Input",
            multiValue = False)

        check_1.value = True
        #jedenasty
        check_2 = arcpy.Parameter(
            displayName = "Zaznacz aby polaczyc pliki CSV w jeden - odznaczenie spowoduje brak laczenia",
            name = "check2",
            datatype = "GPBoolean",
            parameterType = "Optional",
            direction = "Input",
            multiValue = False)



        p = [inside, rodzaj, klasy, wojewodztwa_string,
            kolumny, warstwa, wyrazenie, folder_xml, folder_csv,
            check_1, check_2]


        return p

    def isLicensed(self):
        """Set whether tool is licensed to execute."""
        return True

    def updateParameters(self, parameters):
        """Modify the values and properties of parameters before internal
        validation is performed.  This method is called whenever a parameter
        has been changed."""


        wejsciowa_gdb = parameters[0]
        wybrana_geometria = parameters[1]
        lista_klas = parameters[2]
        wybor_wojewodztwa = parameters[3]
        wybor_kolumny = parameters[4]
        check_box_wartosc_1 = parameters[9].value
        check_box_wartosc_2 = parameters[10].value
        lista_klas.enabled = 0

        arcpy.env.workspace = wejsciowa_gdb.value
        fclist = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses()
        fc_o_wybranej_geometrii = []

        wybor = wybrana_geometria.valueAsText

        if check_box_wartosc_2 and check_box_wartosc_1 == False:
            parameters[0].enabled = 0
            parameters[1].enabled = 0
            parameters[3].enabled = 0
            parameters[4].enabled = 0
            parameters[5].enabled = 0
            parameters[6].enabled = 0

        if check_box_wartosc_1 and check_box_wartosc_2 == False:
            parameters[0].enabled = 1
            parameters[1].enabled = 1
            parameters[3].enabled = 1
            parameters[4].enabled = 1
            parameters[5].enabled = 1
            parameters[6].enabled = 1

        for fc in fclist:
            try:
                split_nazwy = fc.split('_')
                if len (split_nazwy) == 2 and split_nazwy[1] == wybor:
                    fc_o_wybranej_geometrii.append(fc)

            except IndexError:
                pass


        lista_klas.value = fc_o_wybranej_geometrii

        if lista_klas.value:
            fcs = lista_klas.value.exportToString()
            fcs_lista = fcs.split(";")
            wybor_wojewodztwa.filter.list = fcs_lista

        if wybrana_geometria.value:
            if wybor == 'ln':
                lista_ln = [
                    'highway', 'waterway', 'boundary'
                ]
                wybor_kolumny.filter.list = lista_ln

            elif wybor == 'pt':
                lista_pt = [
                    'natural', 'aeroway', 'historic',
                    'leisure', 'waterway', 'shop',
                    'railway', 'tourism', 'highway',
                    'amenity'
                ]
                wybor_kolumny.filter.list = lista_pt

            elif wybor == 'ply':
                lista_ply = [
                    'landuse', 'building', 'natural',
                    'amenity'
                ]
                wybor_kolumny.filter.list = lista_ply 



    def updateMessages(self, parameters):
        """Modify the messages created by internal validation for each tool
        parameter.  This method is called after internal validation."""

    def execute(self, parameters, messages):
        # Zmienne
        # -*- coding: CP1250 -*-
        arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True
        tymczasowa_nazwa = "tymczasowaNazwaDlaFC"
        gdb = parameters[0].valueAsText
        user_geometry_choice = parameters[1].valueAsText
        user_wojewodztwo_choice = parameters[3].valueAsText
        user_column_choice = parameters[4].valueAsText
        user_expression = parameters[6].valueAsText
        dir_xml = parameters[7].valueAsText
        dir_csv = parameters[8].valueAsText
        field_osm = 'OSMID'
        xml_parent_way = 'way'
        xml_parent_node = 'node'
        xml_atr_parent = 'id'
        xml_child = 'tag'
        xml_atr_child = 'k'
        xml_value_child_1 = 'name'
        xml_value_child_2 = 'v'
        xml_value_child_3 = 'ele'
        xml_value_child_4 = 'addr:housenumber'
        xml_value_child_5 = 'ref'
        id_csv = 'id_robocze'
        id_csv_2 = 'id_elementu'
        nazwa_csv = 'nazwa'
        natural_name = "nazwa_ele"
        natural_name_2 = "wysokosc"
        building_name = "budynki_nazwa"
        building_name_2 = "buydnki_numery"
        natural_csv_name = 'natural_nazwa'
        natural_csv_name_2 = 'natural_wysokosc'
        building_csv_name =  'budynki_nazwa'
        building_csv_name_2 = 'budynki_numery'
        highway_name = 'ulice'
        highway_name_2 = 'nr_drogi'
        highway_csv_name = 'ulice'
        highway_csv_name_2 = 'nr_drogi'
        check_box_wartosc_1 = parameters[9].value
        check_box_wartosc_2 = parameters[10].value
        dir_natural = os.path.join(
            dir_csv,'Polska_{0}_{1}.csv'.format(natural_csv_name,
                        user_geometry_choice))
        dir_natural_2 = os.path.join(
            dir_csv,'Polska_{0}_{1}.csv'.format(natural_csv_name_2,
                        user_geometry_choice))
        dir_any = os.path.join(
            dir_csv,'Polska_{0}_{1}.csv'.format(user_column_choice, 
                        user_geometry_choice))
        dir_building = os.path.join(
            dir_csv,'Polska_{0}_{1}.csv'.format(building_csv_name,
                        user_geometry_choice))
        dir_building_2 = os.path.join(
            dir_csv,'Polska_{0}_{1}.csv'.format(building_csv_name_2,
                        user_geometry_choice))
        dir_highway = os.path.join(
            dir_csv,'Polska_{0}_{1}.csv'.format(highway_csv_name,
                            user_geometry_choice))
        dir_highway_2 = os.path.join(
            dir_csv,'Polska_{0}_{1}.csv'.format(highway_csv_name_2,
                            user_geometry_choice))

        # Selekcja z geobazy plikow, ktore zostana wykorzystane do stworzenia list fc
        if check_box_wartosc_1:
            selektor_pre( 
                gdb, user_geometry_choice, user_wojewodztwo_choice,
                user_column_choice, tymczasowa_nazwa, user_expression)

        get_csv(
            gdb, user_geometry_choice, user_column_choice, field_osm, dir_xml, 
            xml_parent_node, xml_atr_parent, xml_child, xml_atr_child, 
            xml_value_child_1, xml_value_child_3, dir_csv, natural_csv_name, 
            natural_csv_name_2, id_csv, natural_name, natural_name_2, 
            xml_value_child_4, building_csv_name, building_csv_name_2, 
            building_name, building_name_2, xml_value_child_2, nazwa_csv,
            xml_parent_way, highway_csv_name, highway_csv_name_2,
            highway_name, highway_name_2, xml_value_child_5,
            user_geometry_choice, user_column_choice, check_box_wartosc_1, 
            check_box_wartosc_2, id_csv_2, dir_natural, dir_natural_2, dir_any,
            dir_building, dir_building_2, dir_highway, dir_highway_2)

        return

class Przygotowanie_do_eksportu(object):
    def __init__(self):
        """Define the tool (tool name is the name of the class)."""
        self.label = "Eliminacja datasetow"
        self.description = "Skrypt przygotowuje dane w geobazie, aby spelnialy wymagania nastepnego skryptu."
        self.canRunInBackground = False


    def getParameterInfo(self):
        """Define parameter definitions"""
                # Pierwszy parametr
        inside = arcpy.Parameter(
            displayName="Wejsciowa geobaza",
            name="in_gdb",
            datatype="DEWorkspace",
            parameterType="Required",
            direction="Input")

        p =[inside]
        return p

    def isLicensed(self):
        """Set whether tool is licensed to execute."""
        return True

    def updateParameters(self, parameters):
        """Modify the values and properties of parameters before internal
        validation is performed.  This method is called whenever a parameter
        has been changed."""

    def updateMessages(self, parameters):
        """Modify the messages created by internal validation for each tool
        parameter.  This method is called after internal validation."""

    def execute(self, parameters, messages):

        arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True


        arcpy.env.workspace = parameters[0].valueAsText
        alt = arcpy.env.workspace
        datalist = arcpy.ListDatasets()

        #clears gdb out of data sets
        for data in datalist:
            for fc in arcpy.ListFeatureClasses("*", "ALL", data):
                czesc = fc.split("_") 
                arcpy.FeatureClassToFeatureClass_conversion(
                    fc, alt, '{0}_{1}'.format(czesc[0], czesc[2]))
            arcpy.Delete_management(data)


        return

def import_excel(
        in_excel, out_gdb):

    """
    Opens excel file  from path
    Make a list from sheets in file
    Iterates through sheets
    """
    workbook = xlrd.open_workbook(in_excel)
    sheets = [sheet.name for sheet in workbook.sheets()]
    for sheet in sheets:
        out_table = os.path.join(
            out_gdb,
            arcpy.ValidateTableName(
                "{0}".format(sheet),
                out_gdb))

        arcpy.ExcelToTable_conversion(in_excel, out_table, sheet)

def iter_kolumny(
        user_input, tymczasowa_mazwa,
        warunek):
    """
    Selection based on user choice

    """
    lista_kolumn = user_input.split(";")
    arcpy.AddMessage(
        "Wybrales nastepujace parametry: {0}".format(lista_kolumn))
    fc_lista = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses()
    for fc in fc_lista:
        czlon_nazwy = fc.split("_")
        for kolumna in lista_kolumn:
            arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(fc, tymczasowa_mazwa)
            try:
                arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management(
                    tymczasowa_mazwa, "NEW_SELECTION", '{0}{1}'.format(kolumna, warunek))
                arcpy.CopyFeatures_management(
                    tymczasowa_mazwa, '{0}_{1}_{2}'.format(czlon_nazwy[0], kolumna, czlon_nazwy[1]))
            except arcpy.ExecuteError:
                pass
        arcpy.Delete_management(fc)


def kolumny_split(
        user_input, tymczasowa_mazwa, warunek, 
        gdb, wojewodztwa_shp, boundary_ply):
    """
    After iter_kolumny call faulty column is deleted,
    and new fc is imported which will be substitute for it

    """
    iter_kolumny(
        user_input, tymczasowa_mazwa, warunek)
    arcpy.Delete_management(
        'Polska_boundary_ply')
    arcpy.FeatureClassToFeatureClass_conversion(
         wojewodztwa_shp, gdb, 'GraniceWojewodztw')
    arcpy.FeatureClassToFeatureClass_conversion(
         boundary_ply, gdb, 'Polska_boundary_ply')

def listy_append(
    listaFc, liniowa, polygon, punkty):
    """
    Simple list appender

    """
    for fc in listaFc:
        czlon_nazwy = fc.split("_")
        if czlon_nazwy[1] == "ln":
            liniowa.append(fc)
        elif czlon_nazwy[1] == "ply":
            polygon.append(fc)
        elif czlon_nazwy[1] == "pt":
            punkty.append(fc)

def nadaj_domene(
    work_space, wybor_uzytkownika):

    """
    Function firstly makes list out of
    user choice, then appends only those fcs which
    are in gdb, then applies only domains which are wanted by user
    (determined by fc choice)
    """
    arcpy.env.workspace = work_space

    lista_kolumn = wybor_uzytkownika.split(";")
    all_tabele_gdb = arcpy.ListTables()
    lista_poprawiona_o_kolumny = []

    for tabela in all_tabele_gdb:
        pierwszy_czlon_nazwy = tabela.split("_")[0]
        if pierwszy_czlon_nazwy in lista_kolumn:
            lista_poprawiona_o_kolumny.append(tabela)
        elif pierwszy_czlon_nazwy == 'man':
            lista_poprawiona_o_kolumny.append(tabela)
        else:
            arcpy.Delete_management(tabela)

    for tabela in lista_poprawiona_o_kolumny:
        lista_robocza = []
        lista_robocza.append(tabela)
        nazwa_domeny = lista_robocza[0]
        arcpy.TableToDomain_management(
            tabela, 'CODE', 'DESCRIPTION', work_space, nazwa_domeny, '-', 'REPLACE')
        arcpy.Delete_management(tabela)

def selektor_pre(
        baza_in, geometria, wojewodztwa, 
        kolumna, tymczasowa_nazwa, user_expression):

    """
    Selects features based on user expression
    """
    arcpy.env.workspace = baza_in

    fc_lista = wojewodztwa.split(';')
    arcpy.AddMessage(fc_lista)
    for fc in fc_lista:
        arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(
            fc, tymczasowa_nazwa)
        arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management(
            tymczasowa_nazwa, "NEW_SELECTION", user_expression)
        arcpy.CopyFeatures_management(
            tymczasowa_nazwa, '{0}_{1}'.format(fc, kolumna))
        arcpy.AddMessage(
            'Seleckja skonczona dla {0}_{1}'.format(fc, kolumna))

def compare_save_to_csv(
        gdb, pole_osm, xml_folder,
        kolumna, parent,atrybut_parent, child, 
        child_atrybut, child_value_1, child_value_2,
        csv_dir, nazwa_pliku, nazwa_id, nazwa_atrybutu,
        user_geometry_choice):

    """
    Iterates over feature classes in geodatabase,
    checks for only those which user needs,
    creates list of ids which will be used in xml_parser
    """
    arcpy.env.workspace = gdb
    wszystkie_fc = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses()

    for fc in wszystkie_fc:
        try:
            split = fc.split('_')
            if split[2] == kolumna and split[1] == user_geometry_choice:
                czesc_nazwy = split[0]
                geom = split[1]
                nazwa_pliku = '{0}_{1}'.format(kolumna, geom)

                lista_id_arcgis = [row[0]
                    for row in arcpy.da.SearchCursor(fc, pole_osm)]

                arcpy.AddMessage("Dlugosc listy: {0}".format(
                    str(len(lista_id_arcgis))))

                xml_parser(
                    '{0}\{1}.xml'.format(xml_folder, czesc_nazwy), 
                    lista_id_arcgis, parent, 
                    atrybut_parent, child, child_atrybut, 
                    child_value_1, child_value_2, nazwa_pliku, 
                    csv_dir, nazwa_id, nazwa_atrybutu,czesc_nazwy)

        except IndexError:
            pass

def compare_save_to_csv_wyjatek(
        gdb, user_geometry_choice, user_column_choice,
        pole_osm, xml_folder, kolumna, parent, atrybut_parent, 
        child, child_atrybut, child_value_1, child_value_2, 
        child_value_3, sciezka_csv, csv_name, csv_name_2,
        nazwa_id, nazwa_atrybutu, nazwa_atrybutu_2):


    """
    Iterates over feature classes in geodatabase,
    checks for only those which user needs,
    creates list of ids which will be used in xml_parser_wyjatki
    """
    arcpy.env.workspace = gdb
    wszystkie_fc = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses()

    for fc in wszystkie_fc:
        try:
            split = fc.split('_')

            if split[2] == kolumna and split[1] == user_geometry_choice:

                czesc_nazwy = split[0]
                lista_id_arcgis = [row[0]
                                    for row in arcpy.da.SearchCursor(fc, pole_osm)]

                arcpy.AddMessage("Dlugosc listy: {0}".format(
                    str(len(lista_id_arcgis))))

                xml_parser_wyjatki(
                    '{0}\{1}.xml'.format(xml_folder, czesc_nazwy),
                    lista_id_arcgis, parent, atrybut_parent, child, child_atrybut, 
                    child_value_1, child_value_2, child_value_3, sciezka_csv, 
                    csv_name, csv_name_2, nazwa_id, nazwa_atrybutu, nazwa_atrybutu_2, czesc_nazwy)

        except IndexError:
            pass

def merge_csv(
        sciezka_csv, fragment_nazwy, nazwa_csv):
    """
    Merges csv in specifed directory based on name scheme
    """
    results = pd.DataFrame([])
    for counter, file in enumerate(glob.glob("{0}\*{1}*".format(sciezka_csv, fragment_nazwy))):
        name_dataframe = pd.read_csv(
            file, usecols=[0, 1],encoding = 'CP1250' )
        results = results.append(
            name_dataframe)
        results.to_csv(
            '{0}\{1}.csv'.format(sciezka_csv, nazwa_csv), encoding = 'CP1250')


def zapis_do_csv(
        lista_1, lista_2, nazwa_1, 
        nazwa_2, csv_name, katalog, 
        czesc_nazwy):
    """
    Saves to CSV, based on 2 lists.
    """
    raw_data = {nazwa_1: lista_1,
                nazwa_2: lista_2}
    df = pd.DataFrame(raw_data, columns=[nazwa_1, nazwa_2])
    df.to_csv(
        '{0}\{1}_{2}.csv'.format(katalog, czesc_nazwy, csv_name), 
        index=False, header=True, encoding = 'CP1250')


def xml_parser(
        xml, lista_agis, parent, 
        atrybut_parent, child, child_atrybut,
        child_value_1, child_value_2, nazwa_pliku,
        sciezka_csv, nazwa_id, nazwa_atrybutu, 
        czesc_nazwy):
    """
    Function to pick from xml files tag values.
    Firstly it creates tree of xml file and then
    goes each level down and when final condtion is fullfiled
    id and value from xml file is appended to list in the end of
    xml file list is saved to CSV.

    """
    rootElement = ET.parse(xml).getroot()
    l1 = []
    l2 = []
    for subelement in rootElement:
        if subelement.tag == parent:
            if subelement.get(atrybut_parent) in lista_agis:
                for sselement in subelement:
                    if sselement.tag == child:
                        if sselement.attrib[child_atrybut] == child_value_1:
                            l1.append(
                                subelement.get(atrybut_parent))
                            l2.append(
                                sselement.get(child_value_2))

    zapis_do_csv(
        l1, l2, nazwa_id, 
        nazwa_atrybutu, nazwa_pliku, 
        sciezka_csv, czesc_nazwy)

    arcpy.AddMessage('Zapisalem {0}'.format(nazwa_pliku))
    arcpy.AddMessage('Zapsialem tyle id: {0}'.format((len(l1))))
    arcpy.AddMessage('Zapsialem tyle nazw: {0}'.format((len(l2))))

def xml_parser_wyjatki(
        xml, lista_agis, 
        parent, atrybut_parent, child, 
        child_atrybut, child_value_1, child_value_2, 
        child_value_3, sciezka_csv, nazwa_pliku, nazwa_pliku_2,
        nazwa_id, nazwa_atrybutu, nazwa_atrybutu_2, czesc_nazwy):
    """
    Function to pick from xml files tag values.
    Firstly it creates tree of xml file and then
    goes each level down and when final condtion is fullfiled
    id and value from xml file is appended to list in the end of
    xml file list is saved to CSV.

    Added 'elif' for some feature classes that are described
    by 2 value tags.

    """
    rootElement = ET.parse(xml).getroot()
    l1 = []
    l2 = []
    l3 = []
    l4 = []

    for subelement in rootElement:
        if subelement.tag == parent:
            if subelement.get(atrybut_parent) in lista_agis:
                for sselement in subelement:
                    if sselement.tag == child:
                        if sselement.attrib[child_atrybut] == child_value_1:
                            l1.append(
                                subelement.get(atrybut_parent))
                            l2.append(
                                sselement.get(child_value_2))
                            arcpy.AddMessage('Dodalem {0}'.format(sselement.get(child_value_2)))
                        elif sselement.attrib[child_atrybut] == child_value_3:
                            l3.append(
                                subelement.get(atrybut_parent))
                            l4.append(
                                sselement.get(child_value_2))
                            arcpy.AddMessage('Dodalem {0}'.format(sselement.get(child_value_2)))

        zapis_do_csv(
            l1, l2, 
            nazwa_id, nazwa_atrybutu, 
            nazwa_pliku, sciezka_csv, czesc_nazwy)

        zapis_do_csv(
            l3, l4, 
            nazwa_id, nazwa_atrybutu_2,
            nazwa_pliku_2, sciezka_csv, czesc_nazwy) 

def replace_csv(
        csv, symbol_1, symbol_2):
    '''
    Function replace certain symbol to prevent 
    ArcGIS Pro from crashing during table import.
    '''
    my_csv_path = csv

    with open(my_csv_path, 'r') as f:
        my_csv_text = f.read()

    find_str = symbol_1
    replace_str = symbol_2

    csv_str = re.sub(find_str, replace_str, my_csv_text)

    with open(my_csv_path, 'w') as f:
        f.write(csv_str)

def get_csv(
        gdb, geom_choice, column_choice, field_osm, dir_xml, 
        xml_parent_node, xml_atr_parent, xml_child, xml_atr_child, 
        xml_value_child_1, xml_value_child_3, dir_csv, natural_csv_name, 
        natural_csv_name_2, id_csv, natural_name, natural_name_2, 
        xml_value_child_4, building_csv_name, building_csv_name_2, 
        building_name, building_name_2, xml_value_child_2, nazwa_csv,
        xml_parent_way, highway_csv_name, highway_csv_name_2,
        highway_name, highway_name_2, xml_value_child_5, user_geometry_choice,
        user_column_choice, check_box_wartosc_1, check_box_wartosc_2, 
        id_csv_2, dir_natural, dir_natural_2, dir_any, dir_building, 
        dir_building_2, dir_highway, dir_highway_2):


    '''
    Combination of all other functions to deliver new fields in feature
    classes in geodatabase.
    '''
    wybrana_kolumna = column_choice


    if geom_choice == 'pt':
        if wybrana_kolumna == 'natural':
            if check_box_wartosc_1:
                compare_save_to_csv_wyjatek(
                    gdb, user_geometry_choice, user_column_choice,
                    field_osm, dir_xml, wybrana_kolumna, 
                    xml_parent_node, xml_atr_parent, xml_child, 
                    xml_atr_child, xml_value_child_1, xml_value_child_2, 
                    xml_value_child_3, dir_csv, natural_csv_name, 
                    natural_csv_name_2, id_csv, natural_name, natural_name_2)

            if check_box_wartosc_2:

                tupel_pt = (
                    [dir_natural],
                    [dir_natural_2]) 

                list(starmap(
                    merge_csv, tupel_pt))

                tupel_pt_2 = (
                    [dir_natural, ';', ' '],
                    [dir_natural, ':', ' '],
                    [dir_natural_2, ';', ' '],
                    [dir_natural_2, ':', ' '])

                list(starmap(
                    replace_csv, tupel_pt_2))

                tupel_pt_3 = (
                    [dir_natural, gdb, id_csv_2, id_csv, 
                    'Polska_natural_pt', field_osm, natural_name],
                    [dir_natural_2, gdb, id_csv_2, id_csv, 
                    'Polska_natural_pt', field_osm, natural_name_2])

                list(starmap(
                    import_fix_join, tupel_pt_3))

        else:
            if check_box_wartosc_1:
                compare_save_to_csv(
                        gdb, field_osm, dir_xml, wybrana_kolumna, 
                        xml_parent_node, xml_atr_parent, xml_child, 
                        xml_atr_child, xml_value_child_1, xml_value_child_2,
                        dir_csv, wybrana_kolumna, id_csv, nazwa_csv, user_geometry_choice)

            if check_box_wartosc_2:
                merge_csv(
                        dir_csv, wybrana_kolumna,
                        'Polska_{0}_{1}'.format(wybrana_kolumna, geom_choice))

                tupel_pt_4 = (
                    [dir_any, ':', ' '],
                    [dir_any, ';', ' '])

                list(starmap(
                    replace_csv, tupel_pt_4))

                import_fix_join(
                    dir_any, gdb, id_csv_2, id_csv, 
                    'Polska_{0}_{1}'.format(wybrana_kolumna, geom_choice),
                    field_osm, nazwa_csv)

    elif geom_choice == 'ply':
        if wybrana_kolumna == 'building':
            if check_box_wartosc_1:
                compare_save_to_csv_wyjatek(
                    gdb, user_geometry_choice, user_column_choice,
                    field_osm, dir_xml, wybrana_kolumna, 
                    xml_parent_way, xml_atr_parent, xml_child, 
                    xml_atr_child, xml_value_child_1, xml_value_child_2, 
                    xml_value_child_4, dir_csv, building_csv_name, 
                    building_csv_name_2, id_csv, building_name, building_name_2)

            if check_box_wartosc_2:

                tupel_ply = ([
                    dir_csv, building_csv_name, 'Polska_{0}_{1}'.format(building_csv_name,
                        user_geometry_choice),
                    dir_csv, building_csv_name_2, 'Polska_{0}_{1}'.format(building_csv_name_2,
                        user_geometry_choice)]) 

                list(starmap(
                    merge_csv, tupel_ply))

                tupel_ply_2 = (
                    [dir_building, ';', ' '],
                    [dir_building, ':', ' '],
                    [dir_building_2, ':', ' '],
                    [dir_building_2, ';', ' '])

                list(starmap(
                    replace_csv, tupel_ply_2))

                tupel_ply_3 = (
                    [dir_building, gdb, id_csv_2, id_csv, 
                    'Polska_building_ply', field_osm, building_name],
                    [dir_building_2, gdb, id_csv_2, id_csv, 
                    'Polska_building_ply', field_osm, building_name_2])

                list(starmap(
                    import_fix_join, tupel_ply_3))

        else:
            if check_box_wartosc_1:
                compare_save_to_csv(
                    gdb, field_osm, dir_xml, wybrana_kolumna, 
                    xml_parent_way, xml_atr_parent, xml_child, 
                    xml_atr_child, xml_value_child_1, xml_value_child_2,
                    dir_csv, wybrana_kolumna, id_csv, nazwa_csv, user_geometry_choice)

            if check_box_wartosc_2:
                merge_csv(
                        dir_csv, wybrana_kolumna,
                        'Polska_{0}_{1}'.format(wybrana_kolumna, geom_choice))

                tupel_ply_4 = (
                    [dir_any , ':', ' '],
                    [dir_any , ';', ' '])

                list(starmap(
                    replace_csv, tupel_ply_4))

                import_fix_join(
                    dir_any, gdb, id_csv_2, id_csv, 
                    'Polska_{0}_{1}'.format(wybrana_kolumna, geom_choice),
                    field_osm, nazwa_csv)

    elif geom_choice == 'ln':
            if wybrana_kolumna == 'highway':
                if check_box_wartosc_1:
                    compare_save_to_csv_wyjatek(
                        gdb, user_geometry_choice, user_column_choice,
                        field_osm, dir_xml, wybrana_kolumna, 
                        xml_parent_way, xml_atr_parent, xml_child, 
                        xml_atr_child, xml_value_child_1, xml_value_child_2, 
                        xml_value_child_5, dir_csv, highway_csv_name, 
                        highway_csv_name_2, id_csv, highway_name, highway_name_2)

                if check_box_wartosc_2:

                    tupel_ln = ([
                        dir_csv, highway_csv_name, 'Polska_{0}_{1}'.format(highway_csv_name,
                        user_geometry_choice),
                        dir_csv, highway_csv_name_2, 'Polska_{0}_{1}'.format(highway_csv_name_2,
                        user_geometry_choice)]) 

                    list(starmap(
                    merge_csv, tupel_ln))

                    tupel_ln_2 = (
                        [dir_highway, ';', ' '],
                        [dir_highway, ':', ' '],
                        [dir_highway_2, ':', ' '],
                        [dir_highway_2, ';', ' '])

                    list(starmap(
                        replace_csv, tupel_ln_2))

                    tupel_ln_3 = (
                        [dir_building, gdb, id_csv_2, id_csv, 
                        'Polska_highway_ln', field_osm, highway_name],
                        [dir_building_2, gdb, id_csv_2, id_csv, 
                        'Polska_highway_ln', field_osm, highway_name_2])

                    list(starmap(
                        replace_csv, tupel_ln_3))
            else:
                if check_box_wartosc_1:
                    compare_save_to_csv(
                        gdb, field_osm, dir_xml, wybrana_kolumna, 
                        xml_parent_way, xml_atr_parent, xml_child, 
                        xml_atr_child, xml_value_child_1, xml_value_child_2,
                        dir_csv, wybrana_kolumna, id_csv, nazwa_csv, user_geometry_choice)

                if check_box_wartosc_2:
                    merge_csv(
                        dir_csv, wybrana_kolumna,
                        'Polska_{0}_{1}'.format(wybrana_kolumna, geom_choice))

                    tupel_ln_4 = (
                        [dir_any, ':', ' '],
                        [dir_any, ';', ' '])

                    list(starmap(
                        replace_csv, tupel_ln_4))

                    import_fix_join(
                        dir_any, gdb, id_csv_2, id_csv, 
                        'Polska_{0}_{1}'.format(wybrana_kolumna, geom_choice),
                        field_osm, nazwa_csv)

def fix_field(
        tabela , nazwa, pole):
    """
    Imported tables has got not 
    valid field with ID. This fix that problem
    by creating new on in text type, copying value 
    and deleting old one.
    """
    arcpy.AddField_management(
        tabela, nazwa, "TEXT", field_length = 20)
    try:
        with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(tabela, [pole,nazwa]) as cursor:
            for row in cursor:
                row[1] = row[0]
                cursor.updateRow(row)
    except RuntimeError:
        print(row[1])
    del row,cursor
    arcpy.DeleteField_management(tabela, [pole])


def import_fix_join(
        in_table, out_gdb, nazwa,
        id_csv, in_fc, field_osm, 
        pole_to_join):
    """
    Imports table to geodatabase
    Fixes its column
    Join field to feature class.

    """
    arcpy.TableToGeodatabase_conversion(
        [in_table], out_gdb)

    fix_field(
        in_table, nazwa, id_csv)

    pole = [pole_to_join]

    arcpy.env.workspace = out_gdb

    arcpy.JoinField_management(
        in_fc, field_osm, in_table,
        nazwa, pole)
```

**Three scripts in ArcGIS Pro software.**

[image]

**Script number one GUI**

[image]

**Script number two GUI**

[image]

**Script number three GUI**

[image]

Comment: Writing the GUI to have Polish text is not a con if your users are Polish :) Internationalization is a huge and complex subject, but simply targeting one language is not necessarily a bad thing.

Comment: Please do not update the code in your question to incorporate feedback from answers, doing so goes against the Question + Answer style of Code Review. This is not a forum where you should keep the most updated version in your question. Please see *[what you may and may not do after receiving answers](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1765)*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some minor stuff:

- I don't see where `self.tools` is used after initialization - can it be deleted? If you need to keep it, does it need to change? If it doesn't change (if it can be immutable), use a tuple instead of a list.
- CP1250 should be avoided unless you have a really good reason. Everyone should be on UTF-8. Using UTF-8 will allow you to add all of the proper character accents in your strings, which currently appear to be missing.
- Python's naming convention is snake_case for variables and function names, and UpperCamelCase only for classes, so `canRunInBackground` would actually be `can_run_in_background`. Same for other names.
- Avoid naming list variables `l1`, `l2`, etc. They should have a meaningful name according to what they actually store.
- For short function calls such as

  ```
  import_excel(
      excel, gdb)
  ```

  there is no need to split it onto two lines. For calls with many arguments it's fine, but here it's more legible on one line.
- This:

  ```
  wejsciowa_gdb = parameters[0]
  wybrana_geometria = parameters[1]
  lista_klas = parameters[2]
  wybor_wojewodztwa = parameters[3]
  wybor_kolumny = parameters[4]
  ```

  can be abbreviated to

  ```
  wejsciowa_gdb, wybrana_geometria, lista_klas, wybor_wojewodztwa, wybor_kolumny = parameters[:5]
  ```

  there are similar instances elsewhere in your code.
- I suggest making a loop for your checkbox logic:

  ```
  if check_box_wartosc_1 != check_box_wartosc_2:
      enabled = int(check_box_wartosc_1)
      for i in (0, 1, 3, 4, 5, 6):
          parameters[i] = enabled
  ```
- After your `if wybor == 'ln'`, you have several temporary list assignments. You don't need the temporary variables - you can assign the lists directly to `filter.list`.
- The argument list for `get_csv` is a little insane. You should make a class with members for those arguments.

Comment: To avoid confusion, you should mention that the `snake_case` convention is for variables/functions, and `CamelCase` for classes.

Comment: 1# self tools has to stay like that - it is used by my software to create Toolbox which you can see in picture nr 1.

2# Thank you for that advice. I will change that

3# I read pep8 - i know about snake convention, for some names I just forgot to change it (I had some massive changes to do and everyday I find some stuff like this :P) but for some I don't think I can change that, beacuse python toolbox is made with a template (all self.something are not made by me, I can delete some of them such as displayName but cant change them, beacuse toolbox will crush )

Comment: 4# Been aware of that, It's my everyday struggle to have proper names. Thanks for pointing that out.

#5,6,7,8,9 - thanks! New things to me, I will look into that. 
I knew something was wrong with get_csv, but I was unable to find solution! Big thanks for all your effort!